# Py 3.8.2 pip missing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I literally used pip just a day ago and now, even before upgrading, pip seems to have vanished. Python is definitely in my path, but the CMD prompt doesn't recognise pip, keeps saying there's a SyntaxError:

I dld get-pip and ran it in vs code, it said

```
[Running] /usr/bin/env python "c:\Users\P\Desktop\get-pip.py"
The system cannot find the path specified.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 25.392 seconds

[Running] /usr/bin/env python "c:\Users\P\Desktop\get-pip.py"
The system cannot find the path specified.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.086 seconds

[Running] /usr/bin/env python "c:\Users\P\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
The system cannot find the path specified.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.143 seconds
```

I was trying to load pygame and that's when it started. Any suggestions are welcome, also here's my PATH directory:

```
C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\Scripts;C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: Please [edit] post to show the ``SyntaxError`` and its traceback. Does ``python3`` exist? Can you run ``python3 -m pip``? Your ``PATH`` suggests that you are on windows, but trying to run ``/usr/bin/env python`` suggest UNIX - which is it?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` - is a linux statement. Isn't your script designed to run in linux, or in a linux emulator (like having Git Bash/Cygwin) installed on your Windows system? Regardless, as [MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi) said, you provide insufficient. Change that and you'll get up-vote.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the 8.2,don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file is just not there? You have to [download](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) the get-pip.py file before you can use it.

Comment: Probably not the issue. The error message seems to arrive from the shell, not Python. This meas that either `/usr/bin/env` or `python` cannot be found. If it was an issue in Python, there would have been a stack trace.

Comment: It was in vs code, so yeh the shell, but called output in vs code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, uninstalled the 8.2 and went back to the 8.1,working fine now, with pip. Thanks for all the help, much appreciated.